# Javascript with local storage from console

Tags: javascript, sql, console, local-storage, storage

I wrote a javascript for a website and i use the script locally from the console(actually tampermonkey). I want to have a external storage(that will constantly grow) that i can communicate with from the script.What is the best way to do that?Could i somehow connect to a sql database with my own php somehow?

Comment: There is the localstorage for that. You can use a lib to use it, like http://www.taffydb.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the code for a web page hosted at www.example.com, you can use a [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) object (or certain [similar options](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/)) to store a limited amount of data which will persist across sessions and be available offline.  In principle you could have a JS library that implements an SQL database on top of one of these local storage methods, but I'm not aware of any examples and it seems like overkill.

No browser will allow a general website to store unlimited local data, or guarantee its persistence, for obvious security reasons.

Your page can, of course, access an SQL database hosted at www.example.com, by using XMLHttpRequest to read and write data through scripts you have set up on the server (e.g. `http://www.example.com/my_json_data.php`).  This would be the usual approach.

If you *also* control the setup of the client computer, then it is possible for a page at www.example.com to access a *local* database in the same way, e.g. your script can read data from `http://localhost/my_json_data.php`.  This will violate the browser's same-origin policy, and so you will need to configure the local HTTP server to allow the [cross-origin request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).  You will also need to set up the SQL database, the HTTP server and the access scripts on each client computer.  But this is almost certainly not the best or easiest approach, even for an intranet application.